# How to created automated Journey for Google Analytics 360 contacts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, automation, google-analytics

I have integrated Google Analytics 360 with my marketing cloud account. I see it as a Synchronized Data Source in Contact Builder and I can pull it into my Journey in Journey Builder. But, I want this journey to be sent on an Automated Schedule. I cannot do this until I set up something in Automation Studio. I think I need to setup a synchronized data extension with this google Analytics 360 data, but I can't figure it out. How do I send an automated journey to my Google Analytics 360 contacts?

Comment: you can set your journey entry to be re-occurring, unsure what else you are looking to do

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using a GA360 audience is that it's instant entry as a person is added to the audience. If you really need it to run your journey at a specific time you could maybe try:

1. Putting a Wait period at the start of the journey with a 1 minute wait on it, but also clicking the "Extend wait duration until specific time" button. This would allow the records to all effectively "start" the journey at the same time once a day even though they enter they enter over the course of a day; or
2. Have an empty journey that does nothing but runs off your GA360 data. This will allow you to collect the people that fall into the audience in a data extension for use later. Then you build your real journey that runs from a scheduled automation.